# How to add several examples to response in Swagger without breaking Codegen?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

I've been trying to add examples to my Swagger API according to the [official docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/) (see last codeblock of *Request and Response Body Examples*) but it does not seem to work as expected.

Considering the following minimal example:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: Desc
  version: "1"
  title: Title
paths:
  /stuff:
    post:
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        201:
          description: It worked
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/definitions/StatusMessage"
              examples:
                Success without message:
                  value:
                    code: "00000"
                Success with message:
                  value:
                    code: "00000"
                    message: "All right"
definitions:
  StatusMessage:
    type: object
    description: Response with code and optional message
    properties:
      code:
        type: string
      message:
        type: string
    required:
    - code
```

I want to provide to sample responses, one with the optional property `message` present and the other one without. However, the aforementioned YAML file yields wrong results in the generated API Class:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "stuffPost", notes = "", tags={  })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "It worked") })
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff",
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
default ResponseEntity<Void> stuffPost() { /*default implementation*/ }
```

The `produces` property is not present and the return type is wrong! Furthermore, this does not compile in the [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/): the `responses` property `should NOT have additional properties`.

---

I'v changed it to get a "valid" example in the Swagger Editor but the generated code is also wrong. See below:

```
paths:
  /stuff:
    post:
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        201:
          description: It worked
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/StatusMessage"
          examples:
            Success without message:
              code: "00000"
            Success with message:
              code: "00000"
              message: "All right"
```

The generated method is:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "stuffPost", notes = "", response = StatusMessage.class, tags={  })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "It worked", response = StatusMessage.class) })
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff",
    produces = { "application/json", "Success without message", "Success with message" }, 
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
default ResponseEntity<StatusMessage> stuffPost() { /*default implementation*/ }
```

This time, the `produces` property is there but completely off!

---

**How can I get this to work?** It works if I use the second version with `application/json` as key for the example title but that prevents me from adding more examples because of duplicated key.

Comment: You are mixing OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`) and OpenAPI 3.0 (`openapi: 3.0.0`) syntax, which is likely why this does not work. For example, `content` and `examples` are OpenAPI 3.0 keywords, but `definitions` is a 2.0 keyword. Use http://editor.swagger.io to check your spec for syntax errors, then try again.

Comment: Hi @Helen, thanks for your help (again). I will check my versions and try again. Is the multiple example case even supported in OpenAPI 2.0? If yes, where can I find a working example of this case?

Comment: Nope, `examples` (plural form) are not supported in OpenAPI 2.0. 2.0 only supports `example` - check out the 2.0 guide for [Adding Examples](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/adding-examples/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113116/helen)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753937/how-to-add-several-examples-to-response-in-swagger-without-breaking-codegen/52813188#comment92452928_52753937):

> This example is mixing OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`) and OpenAPI 3.0 (`openapi: 3.0.0`) syntax. For example, `content` and `examples` are OpenAPI 3.0 keywords, but `definitions` is a 2.0 keyword.
>
> `examples` (plural form) are not supported in OpenAPI 2.0, which only supports `example` - check out the 2.0 guide for [Adding Examples](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/adding-examples/).

A workaround I've found for this problem in OpenAPI 2.0 is as follows:

```
paths:
  /stuff:
    post:
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        201:
          description: It worked
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/StatusMessage"
          examples:
            - code: "00000"
              message: "All right"
            - code: "00000"
```

This shows both examples (with `0` and `1` as title) and does not break Codegen.