# How to generate different example using same schema for swagger documentation using @ApiModel annotation

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I want to use `Order` class schema to show two different examples in Swagger UI. Could you help me what annotations to use here? I am using Spring MVC with Swagger 2.0

Model :

```
public class Order {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Order Event", required = true, example = "Pending/Declined/Charged")
    private String event;

    private String status;

    private String reason;
}
```

Example 1:

```
{  
  "event": "PENDING",
  "status": "Approved"   
}
```

Example 2:

```
{  
  "event": "DECLINED",
  "status": "denied",
  "reason": "payment error"
}
```

Comment: Swagger 2.0 does not support multiple examples. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753937/how-to-add-several-examples-to-response-in-swagger-without-breaking-codegen#comment92454983_52753937)

Comment: Thanks for responding. so can I get some examples for swagger 3.0 showing how to add two examples of the same schema using annotation?

Comment: you could use the Swagger Codegen tool to generate code with multiple examples. The generated code should represent what you need. I haven't done it myself so I couldn't really tell you more